Не обновляется css и js на сайте после обновления исходников сайта
У меня есть вдс и на нем стоит VestaCP. Обновил сайт залил новые файлы, но когда захожу на него index.html меняется а js и css нет. При этом если изменить директорию где она хранятся на новую то все работает. Как это исправить?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Не забывать чистить кэш браузера

кеш я чистил но не помогло
